# how to create two or more view with in a single view

Tags: views

I want to create a view which outputs as page . Within that view ,i need to create two or more views they will react based on the arguments to their parent view

Comment: What do you mean by "the value to their parent view"?
Are you referring to exposed filters? - If so you can try adding attachment displays - which can inherit the user input from the parent view.

Comment: Sorry @rooby I mean to say arguments

Comment: If you add an attachment display it has an option "Inherit contextual filters". Set that to "Yes" (which is the default) and it will inherit the arguments from the parent view. It is more limited than a block though in terms of where you can place it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a views attachment to the main parent view. Fist you create a new Views Display, say a block. then on the parent view, attach that view to it. Now turn on inherit contextual filters so you can pass the arguments over to the other view. If you want finer control with the output and fields you can try: http://drupal.org/project/views_php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view)?

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

Comment: Ya i tried that module it's working for simple case with one contextual filter. I have to use more than two filter. What i do